# generating links for nested menu using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, menu, nested-lists

I have went through dozens and dozens of similar questions, but non that actually tackle my specific requirement.

I have a mysql table that are defined by three variables (id, name, pid)

The nested menu is generated with the following function:

```
function get_categories($parent = '0') {
    $html = '<ul id="menu">';
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `categories` WHERE `pid` = '$parent'");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        $current_id = $row['id'];
        $html .= '<li><a href="">' . $row['name'] . '</a>';
        $has_sub = NULL;
        $has_sub = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`pid`) FROM `categories` WHERE `pid` = '$current_id'"));
        if($has_sub) {
            $html .= get_categories($current_id);
        }
        $html .= '</li>';
    }
    $html .= '</ul>';
    return $html;
}
print get_categories();
```

My question is how I may generate the link so that it is presented in a 'pretty url' manner.
ex. `<a href="/parent_category/sub_category/sub_sub_category">`?
Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: better to have category_path from child to parent in database

Comment: I know, but was wondering if there is a way to generate that path from the parent/child relation (from existing table).